# Blender Cycles 2.69 on Ubuntu Server 13.10 64bit

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linux, versions

I trying to render an image/animation using Amazon EC2, but Cycles rendering fails with this message:

```
Fra:1 Mem:17.09M (0.00M, Peak 17.09M) | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene,
RenderLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube Illegal instruction (core
dumped)
```

For testing I used the Blender default scene, I only changed the rendering engine to Cycles. (To make sure it,s not some advanced feature that is broken).
Using the default Blender Renderer seems to work fine.

I installed the current version of Blender according to [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339634/downloading-latest-blender-version-from-ppa/).

I start rendering using this command :  `blender -noaudio -b test.blend -f 1`

Using the default version of Blender (2.66) works for the default scene, but is not compatible with the scene I want to render (results in empty images). I would prefer to render using 2.69 instead of converting my scene for compatibility with 2.66.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get it to work:
Instead of using the launchpad version I downloaded the GNU/Linux version from Blender site. Using this version Cycles works fine.